# Android install/uninstall log

Tags: android, log-analysis, installer, uninstall, play-store

I am looking for an app that will display a log of all app installations and uninstallations. Each log entry should display the date and optionally also the time of installation or uninstallation along with the app name and app icon of the corresponding app.

The user should be able to view the list in chronological, reverse chronological, or alphabetical order.

One of the reasons this app would be useful is that most devices have limited device memories, causing the user to often have to uninstall an app our set of apps to make room for other ones the user wants to install. Unless the uninstall app is a paid app, the user might lose track of it despite it being useful, and might forget the app name making it difficult or impossible to find the app again for downloading from the play store.

The log should also allow the user to view each last install or uninstall of any given app as part of two separate uninstall and install lists (thus allowing the user to quickly find the names of apps that were deleted directly from the uninstall list).

Does any such Android app exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: such an app would have to track things itself. I've never found that Android keeps a history of uninstalled apps, and I've checked a lot (my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) a.o. creates a device documentation which includes a list of apps installed, with their installation and last update timestamps and more; I had created another document with uninstalled apps if I'd found a possibility to obtain such details). Though I've never stumbled upon such an app, chances are I've simply missed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best app for this I've found to be 'App Usage'. This does the job of keeping a log as well as a whole plethora of other features in a neat and tidy interface.

Comment: Do you have a link that you can [edit] into your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific app, but google supports three ways of viewing your android apps.

- https://play.google.com/apps will show all the apps you've ever installed via your google account.  Unfortunately, there is no search or sort features.
- https://play.google.com/store/myplayactivity will show recent activity
- https://takeout.google.com will allow you to export your google play/store activity.  This will give you a zip file containing a bunch of json files.  This will give you more information (date installed/updated for example).  From there you can import that into excel for sorting.  I found [this document](https://www.howtogeek.com/775651/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-microsoft-excel/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20your%20JSON%20file%20to%20Excel%2C%20you,and%20your%20JSON%20to%20Excel%20conversion%20is%20done.) useful for figuring out how to import data into excel from json.